# Converting CSS data back into an SVG

Tags: vector, css

I have a client who has told me to source their logo from their website, but their logo is CSS information. Is there a resource to convert the css back into vector information?

Comment: css information how? is it a bunch of HTML tags styled with CSS, or an inline SVG, can you [edit] the question to add more details?

Comment: No logo is in "CSS information". You could make one as a personal "challenge" but no commercial project is made like that.

Comment: Often, clients *don't know* what they are talking about. They pick up a buzzword here or there, then use it haphazardly. It's doubtful any logo is only "CSS information" *unless* the logo is nothing more than type and colors - in which case any vector editor could probably recreate it. I think this question is fairly impossible to answer effectively without seeing the logo in question.

Comment: Hi. Can you share the link to the website.  It's probably not possible to answer this without being able to see it. Have you inspected the element on the web page?

Answer (score 1):

No logo is in "CSS information". You could make one as a personal "challenge" but no commercial project is made like that.

A logo "might" be inserted on a web page in different ways tho. A logo might be either raster or vector and can be either as a separate file or an encoded one inside the HTML file, which would be extremely rare. I only mention it because I know it can be done, but I have never, ever seen anyone doing that.

The logo might be called not by the HTML file, but by the CSS file, in that case just see the path to the location of the file inside the CSS file.

A logo might be, as a challenge, done using HTML rectangles assembled as a shape modified by CSS. Maybe someone could encode a logo on a JavaScript file but only if it is part of an animation or something.

But a somehow "normal" way is to insert or embed the **"SVG code"** inside the HTML file (not the CSS file)

So. **Some options:**

1. Find the file.
2. If the file is in SVG format embedded into the HTML file, open the HTML file, copy the text inside  tags, paste it into a new file, and save it as a logo.SVG
3. If really there is no SVG info, zoom in on the webpage, take a screen capture and redraw the logo.